# Mysql select based of results of another select

Tags: mysql

I know this can be done with a scripting language, but doing it one SQL call would be magnificent for my requirement. I need to select all the categories, and parent categories of a product

Say i have these two tables.

```
TABLE 1:categories
|| category || categoryid ||
===========================
|| fightercraft      || 5    

|| spaceship    || 10  

|| ships   || 3
```

And

```
TABLE 2:catrelationships
category || parentcategory
===========================
5  ||  10

10  || 3 

3   ||
```

My restriction is i'm only able to pass one parameter to a query on the first table categories. I know i have a fightercraft category, i need to get the parent categories all in a single column.

```
Select categories.category,catrelationships.category from categories 
JOIN categories on catrelationships.category=categories.id
where categories.id=5
```

Need to return this somehow!

```
RESULT
|| product     || category 

|| fightercraft || 5

|| spaceship  || 10

|| ships  || 3
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there a limit to how deep categories can nest?

Comment: Technically no limit. But generally about 3-5 levels deep. Anything more than that is less than 1% chance.

Comment: There's no difference between table 1 and your result set.

Comment: My good man, you are right..let me update that.

Comment: Ok i've updated it, i think that now makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do it, but if you're willing to assume there's limit on the depth of nested categories, the following should do what you want:

```
SELECT p.product
     , c2.product AS category
  FROM products p
  JOIN (
        SELECT c1.category AS c1
             , c1.parentcategory AS c2
             , c2.parentcategory AS c3
             , c3.parentcategory AS c4
          FROM categories c1
     LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c1.parentcategory = c2.category
     LEFT JOIN categories c3 ON c2.parentcategory = c3.category
        ) c ON p.category = c.c1
   JOIN categories c2 ON c2.category IN (c.c1, c.c2, c.c3, c.c4)
  ORDER BY p.product ASC, c2.category DESC;
```

The above query assumes a maximum nested depth of 4 categories. You can adjust the depth as necessary.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43280/2/0)

Comment: That works perfectly. But i realised i asked the wrong question :(

Comment: I have updated the original question. If anyone can help i well shower you in good karma.

Comment: It's the same logic, probably a little simpler. You should be able to get your results by tweaking my query a bit.

Comment: Thank you shmosel. You have helped a lot. I will transfer good karma to you over the ether. Thanks again man, much appreciated.